# Search Closed Excel Workbook Using ADODB

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to query a closed excel workbook, and have successfully done that.  what i am trying to do is modify my search query: 2 things
1st thing: how to query for a empty cell
2nd thing: query between specific dates (now() & now()-1)--trying to retrieve yesterdays dates from query.. also my column dates are in this format (5/29/2015 7:25 AM)

here is my script i am using below:

```
Sub Pull_Data_from_Excel_with_ADODB()

Dim cnStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim var1
Dim var2
var1 = Date - 1

var2 = "not"

Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\Signin-Database\DATABASE\Signin-Database.xlsm"

    cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"


query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$D:E] WHERE [Time_in] = '" & var1 & " ' AND [Time_out] ='" & var2 & "'"



Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

Cells.Clear
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Dim Cell As Range, i As Long
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe i figured out with many trial an error

here is the latest working code below

```
Sub Pull_Data_from_Excel_with_ADODB()

Dim cnStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim var1
Dim var2
var1 = Now() - 1
var2 = Now()
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\Signin-Database\DATABASE\Signin-Database.xlsm"

    cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"


query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$D:H] WHERE [Time_in] < '" & var2 & "' AND [Time_in] >  '" & var1 & "' AND [Time_out] is null"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

Cells.Clear
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Dim Cell As Range, i As Long
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit





    End With
```

End Sub